# Error on FeathersJS connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I am new to FeathersJS and trying to connect it with PostgreSQL, but I am having trouble with SequelizeConnection, it shows me this error

> info: Feathers application started on http://localhost:3030
>
> error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise
> {"_bitField":18087936,"_fulfillmentHandler0":{"name":"SequelizeConnectionError","parent":{"length":166,"name":"error","severity":"FATAL","code":"28P01","file":"d:\pginstaller_12.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\libpq\auth.c","line":"333","routine":"auth_failed"},"original":{"length":166,"name":"error","severity":"FATAL","code":"28P01","file":"d:\pginstaller_12.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\libpq\auth.c","line":"333","routine":"auth_failed"}},"name":"SequelizeConnectionError","parent":{"length":166,"name":"error","severity":"FATAL","code":"28P01","file":"d:\pginstaller_12.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\libpq\auth.c","line":"333","routine":"auth_failed"},"original":{"length":166,"name":"error","severity":"FATAL","code":"28P01","file":"d:\pginstaller_12.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\libpq\auth.c","line":"333","routine":"auth_failed"}}

Answer (score 1):

This error specifies you enter invalid connection string to connect you to your postgres database.

You need to give a valid connection string like this :

postgres://user:password@host:port/db_name

where :

- user: it's the user to connect in your postgres database,
- password: it's the password of the user,
- host: the hostname where your database is available (for example, "localhost", if postgres is installed in local),
- port: the port by default it's 5432,
- db_name: the name of your database.